# How to handle empty level in hierarchy in MS-Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hierarchical-data

I have table with sample data:

```
+---------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------------+
| region1 |   region2    | region3 | locality | hid             |
+---------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------------+
| england | bedfordshire | beford  | null     | '/1/1/1/'       |
| england | bedfordshire | null    | arshley  | '/1/1/1/'       |
| england | bedfordshire | bedford | kingston | '/1/1/1/1/'     |
+---------+--------------+---------+----------+-----------------+
```

When I get the descendant of bedford, I should not get arshley, is there a way?

If I use `GetLevel()>3`, then I have to handle code for other levels also
ie for region1 descendant..so is there any other way.

Query Used:
Declare @hier hierarchyid
Select @hier = hid from locationtable where region3 = 'bedford' and locality is null
Select * from locationtable  where hid.IsDescendantOf(@hier)=1

Comment: Please post the SQL you are using on the table.

Comment: @EricHauenstein included sql code.